# What is the meaning of $\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}$?

Tags: covariance

I'm reading a paper and this is the main quantity if focuses on. In the above definition

- x = $[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$
- $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of variables.

What is the meaning of this quantity? It looks like a mahalanobis distance, but the covariance is not inverted. Is this quantity something common in statistics? If so, what is it called?

Comment: can you provide a link to the paper? are you sure $\Sigma$ isn't a precision matrix rather than a covariance matrix?

Comment: @BenBolker: it's section 2.1 of http://thierry-roncalli.com/download/erc.pdf

Comment: Note here that the $x_i$ are not random variables, but amounts in a portfolio associated with individual risky assets. I don't know that there's a word for this quantity other than "a quadratic form" ...

Comment: x should be column vector. Then it is the standard error of $Z=x^TY$ while $Var(Y) = \Sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

From the paper you linked to:

> Let $\sigma(x) = \sqrt{x^\intercal\Sigma x} = \sum_i x_i\sigma^2_i +
>  \sum_i \sum_{j \neq i}x_i x_j \sigma_{i,j}$ be the risk of the
>   portfolio.

You could also call it the volatility or standard deviation of your portfolio returns. Note the expression on the right should have a square root sign over both sums:

$$
\sqrt{\sum_i x_i\sigma^2_i +
 \sum_i \sum_{j \neq i}x_i x_j \sigma_{i,j}}.
$$

Personally, I disagree with [user158565](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/158565/user158565); I would not use the phrase "standard error." I usually use that term to refer to standard deviations of parameter estimates.

As [BenBolker](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2126/ben-bolker) is getting at: it is not Mahalanobis distance because the quadratic form uses the covariance matrix, not the inverse covariance matrix (aka the precision matrix or the concentration matrix).

Comment: When do you use the "standard error"?

Comment: @user158565 thanks for pointing out the grammatical typo. It now reads "I usually use that term to refer to standard deviations of parameter estimates"

Comment: Are you sure the quotation is correct?  Besides its inconsistent use of $\sqrt{\cdot},$ the right hand side simply makes no sense.

Comment: @whuber the < sign was incorrectly added by the blockquote button. And I didn't even notice the lack of the square root, wow. See the change I just added